# ComboBox with ActionListener and if-statement

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I'm trying to add an ActionListener to my ComboBox. I want to open a form when a item is selected from the box. I successfully implemented it on a JButton but I can't figure out how to do it in a combobox. Can someone please help me out?

```
    JComboBox<String> valBox = new JComboBox<>();   

    valBox.addItem("Apparat");
    valBox.addItem("Smycke");
    valBox.addItem("Aktie");
    södra.add(valBox);

    valBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (valBox.getSelectedIndex() == 0)
                nyLyss.ApparatForm.form1();
        }
    });
```

The code that I wan't to execute when the first item is selected is this one:

```
    class nyLyss implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        try{
            ApparatForm form1 = new ApparatForm();

            int svar = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(Layout.this, form1);
            if(svar != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
                return;
            String namn = form1.getNamn();
            int inköpspris = form1.getPris();
            int slitage = form1.getPris();
    //      saker ap = new saker(namn, inköpspris, slitage);
    //      alla.add(ap);

        }catch(NumberFormatException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Layout.this, "Felaktig indata!");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: *I successfully implemented it on a JButton*: then add the exact same ActionListener to the combo box as the one you're adding to the button, and it should work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this matter is covered in the official tutorial - [How to Use Combo Boxes: Handling Events on a Combo Box](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html#listeners)

Answer (score 0):

I would solve the problem with a ItemStateChanged listener on my combobox. Here a short example with a combobox called "mycombobox".

```
private void mycomboboxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                            

    System.out.println(mycombobox.getSelectedItem());

}
```

The result is, that the application is printing out the selected item after every change of the selected item in the combobox "mycombobox".